# access master page property from class file

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

How do I access Master page property from .cs file? I tried the following code but I couldn't access it.Please let me know.

### Master Page property:

```
public int TypeID
{
    get
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(this.ViewState["TypeID"]);
    }
    set
    {
        this.ViewState.Remove("TypeID");
        this.ViewState.Add("TypeID", value);
    }
}
```

### data.cs

```
var pageHandler = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;
if (pageHandler  is  System.Web.UI.Page)
{
    typeId = Convert.ToInt32((System.Web.UI.Page)pageHandler).Master.TypeID;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Master` property of a page is typed as `System.Web.UI.MasterPage`. In order to see the `TypeId` property, you need to cast the `Master` to the type of your specific master page.

```
var page = (System.Web.UI.Page)pageHandler
var master = (MyMasterType)page.Master; //Replace MyMasterType with the class name from your masterpage.cs file.
var typeId = master.TypeId;
```

You'll want to be careful casting it to a specific master type if you have multiple master types in your application or if some pages don't have a master page.